# How to write contents of an RTF file to Windows clipboard with one-liner?

Tags: powershell

I know practically nothing about PowerShell but need to do a very specific task: develop a one-liner to write the contents of a RTF file to the Windows clipboard.

I have separate pieces that work, but lack the syntax knowledge to hook it all together.

This little script works, if saved to `blah.ps1` then invoked as `./blah.ps1`, but I need to avoid using a script.

```
$data = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataObject
$rtf = Get-Content -Path foo.rtf -Raw
$data.SetData([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Rtf, $rtf)
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject($data)
```

But I need to express it as a one-liner more like this:

```
Get-Content foo.rtf | $data = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataObject; $data.SetData([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Rtf, $_); [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject($data)
```

which fails with

```
At line:1 char:24
+ Get-Content foo.rtf | $data = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataOb ...
+                        ~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Comment: Why not just `Get-Content foo.rtf | Set-Clipboard`

Comment: Because that puts raw RTF on the plain text part of the clipboard.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thank you

Comment: `pbcopy` on macOS automatically detects the RTF header and puts it into the correct pasteboard, but alas `Set-Clipboard` seem to not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now used @colsw's very helpful suggestion to come up with a better solution. One downside of my original code is that the RTF only persists on the clipboard until the PowerShell instance exits. This is not a problem during interactive development, but it was a dealkiller in my actual usage. *Update: I now know you can call the `SetDataObject` method with `$true` as the second argument (the `copy` argument), to make the clipboard data persist.*

It turns out that you can use a simpler solution to write rich text, which also has the benefit of better persistence.

(If I really wanted a script, I wouldn't hardwire the RTF file path like this, but in my real use case, I have to interpolate a file name at run time.)

Here it is in script form:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$rtf = Get-Content -Path foo.rtf
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText($rtf, [System.Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat]::Rtf)
```

And as an ugly one-liner:

```
powershell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms | Out-Null;[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetText((Get-Content foo.rtf),[Windows.Forms.TextDataFormat]::Rtf)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons (`;`) are used to mimic a newline in one-line scripts, Pipe characters (`|`) are used to pass outputs down the pipeline as inputs, you can turn this into a one-liner that doesn't need either though just by wrapping them inside each other:

```
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject([Windows.Forms.DataObject]::new([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Rtf,(Get-Content -Raw "C:\path\to\file.rtf")))
```

You will likely need to "Add" forms as well, so if that doesn't work:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"|Out-Null;[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject([Windows.Forms.DataObject]::new([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Rtf,(Get-Content -Raw "C:\path\to\file.rtf")))
```

Comment: The first proposal just works! Fantastic.

Comment: jennybryan... I am always curious as to why folks choose a path that they do. Why would this need to be a [one-liner](https://mikefrobbins.com/2019/02/07/whats-a-powershell-one-liner-not-a-powershell-one-liner/)? If you are doing this at an interactive PowerShell console or the like, I get that, but in a script... [well, you know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/04-pipelines?view=powershell-7.1).  There are a few documented ways to handle you use case as the one noted by colsw.

Comment: This provides a semi-supported, minor feature of an R package and I need to shell out to get this RTF on the clipboard. It's not simple to ship a PowerShell script inside a package, sort out its path, and deal with setting execution policy. But if you think I'm missing some other solution, I'm happy to learn more. As I said, I'm pretty ignorant about PowerShell.

Comment: For the record, in actual usage, I did indeed need to "Add" the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly. I actually have to call this from `cmd.exe` via `powershell -Command "..."`, not in an interactive PowerShell instance. The RTF part of the clipboard also only persists for the duration of the PowerShell instance, which is another challenge.